# How do I find if the series $\sum\frac{2^n}{n^2}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

How do I find if the series

$$\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{2^n}{n^2}$$

converges?

I know it diverges but I'm trying to figure out the steps. I tried applying l'hoptital's rule for the divergence test but the result keeps getting bigger... I'm sure there is some simple trick that I'm forgetting but it's driving me nuts. Someone please explain the steps for breaking this one down.

Comment: Did you try to move to new log base? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base

Comment: Well, a series can only converge if the limit of the summands is 0.  2^n is exponential and n^2 is geometric so obviously the limits diverges.

Comment: Are you asking about the series (sum) or the sequence?

Comment: The ratio test is simple and clear, why not use it

Comment: L'hopitals yields $\ln 2*2^n/2n$  Apply it twice you get $\ln^2 2^n/2$ which diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

l'hoptital's rule is the way to go.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n}{n^2}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log(2) \cdot 2^{n}}{2 \cdot n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log(2)^2 \cdot 2^{n}}{2 }$$

So your summands keep getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: Do you mean $\log (2)^2$ instead of $\log(n)^2$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will edit it.

Comment: This is exactly where I'm stuck. How did you get from log(2)*2^n/2n to log(2)^2*2^n/2 ? I get a much longer result when I differentiate log(2)*2^n/2n

Comment: i think I wasnt treating log(2) as a constant and that's why...

Comment: are you using the quotient rule when you derive the second time?

Comment: I end up with $\lim\frac{log(2)^2 * 2^n - 2^n}{n}$

Comment: @TatianaFrank Take the derivative of the top and bottom independently when applying L'Hopital's rule. You are not using the quotient rule!!

Comment: wow ok that's what I was missing. thank you @MathMajor

Comment: @TatianaFrank No problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Ratio test
$$L=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}\frac{n^2}{2^n}=\frac{2}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^2}$$
the $L>1$, so the series diverges

Comment: Better then my answer, because the ratio test is more universal and it is easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n^2}$$

In order to have convergence, the terms must go to $0$.

Comment: Yes I stated in the question description, I tried applying l'hopital's rule for the divergence test and the answer keeps expanding. So your comment is not helpful if you read the description below my question.

Comment: @TatianaFrank Applying L'Hopital's rule twice you get $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log (2)^2 2^n}{2}$

Comment: Your title is asking about the series (sum) not the sequence.  The series can not converge if the terms are positive but do not converge to zero.  So asking about tne limit of the terms is reasonable.  If *that* was your question, you should have asked that and not about the series.

Answer (score 1):

What about simply the $\;n\,-$ th root test?:

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n}{n^2}}=\frac2{\left(\sqrt[n]n\right)^2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}2>1$$

and thus the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Note $2^n > n^2$ for $n \geq 5$ by induction. You need to show $2^n > 2n+1$ for the inductive step; to show this, you can use induction again and here it suffices to show $2^n > 2$ which is trivial.

Then $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{2^n}{n^2} > \sum_{n \geq 5} \frac{2^n}{n^2}  > \sum_{n \geq 5} 1 \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]\ \infty$$

Asymptotically, $n^2 = o(2^n)$ so not only does the series diverge, but it *really* diverges.